# Track clicks on a button and save it to mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to make a simple "recommend" functionality where a user can click a button on a place's page and it increments place.recoms by 1 and saves the new value to the db.
This is what I have so far:

**Place Model:**

```
var placeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
address: String,
image: String,
description: String,
createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
recoms: Number,
author: {
    id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    },
    username: String
},
comments: [
    {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Comment"
    }
]
});
```

**Recommend Place Routes:**

```
router.post('/places/:id', function(req, res) {
    Place.findById(req.params.id, function(err, place){
        if(err){
            req.flash("error", "Something went wrong.");
            res.redirect("back");
        } else {
            place.recoms++;
            place.save();
            res.redirect("/places/" + req.params.id);
        }
    });  
});
```

**Recommend Div on Place's Show Page:**

```
<div id="recommend" class="float-right text-center">
                        <p id="recomCount">
                            <%=place.recoms%> people recomend this place.
                        </p>
                        <form action="/places/<%=place.id%>?_method=PUT" method="post">
                            <a href="/places/<%=place.id%>/recom" id="recomButton" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Recommend this place</a>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

This is how the show page is being rendered:

```
router.get("/places/:id", function(req, res){
    // find place with provided ID
    Place.findById(req.params.id).populate("comments").exec(function(err, foundPlace){
       if(err || !foundPlace) {
           req.flash("error", "Place not found.");
           res.redirect("back");
       } else {
           // render show template with that place
           res.render("places/show", {place: foundPlace});
       }
    });
});
```

At the moment the place.recoms value stays 0 no matter what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it by changing the route to:

```
router.put("/places/:id/recom", function(req, res){
    Place.findById(req.params.id, function(err, place){
        console.log(req.params.id);
        if(err){
            req.flash("error", "Something went wrong.");
            res.redirect("back");
        } else {
            place.recoms++;
            place.save();
            res.redirect("/places/" + req.params.id);
        }
    });  
});
```

And the form to:

```
<form action="/places/<%=place.id%>/recom/?_method=PUT" method="post">
                            <button id="recomButton" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Recommend this place</a>
                        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, just comments on the code.

1. When clicking the recommend button, you are redirecting user to the previous page, before saving the recoms to the model, I don't think that will use the new value.
2. Where and how are you rendering the template that contains the Recommends div?
3. Do you persist the model updates into the DB somewhere?
4. The form's action is a post, it's not being used, is it?

Comment: 1. I'm only redirecting back if there's an error. 3. I don't understand, could you elaborate? For 2. and 4. please take a look at the edited question.

Comment: I found the problem. It wasn't working because I had another put route defined before this one on the same URL, which is used to edit places.
How do I fix that and make both work without, say, incrementing recoms whenever the user edits a place?